# Setting group field of new user safely in firebase realtime db

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set the "group" field of the newly created user only once by doing this which happens only after successful sign up:

```
this.props.firebase
  .makeUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((authUser) => {
    return this.props.firebase.user(authUser.user.uid).set({
      username,
      email,
      rule: 'USER'
    });
  })
```

firebase prop is the instance of this class:

```
class Firebase 
{
  constructor() 
  {
    app.initializeApp(config);

    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.database();
  }

  makeUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

But is it safe to initialize when it is only secured by the rule that checks if the field is not set yet? Couldn't someone inject code that sets it to something else before this code runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this from the client is indeed not secure. Given that your app contains all configuration data that is needed to call the Firebase API, any malicious user can copy this configuration data and call the API themselves.

So they could do this:

```
await this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
this.props.firebase.user(authUser.user.uid).set({
      username,
      email,
      rule: 'ADMIN'
    });
```

And that is probably not what you want. For this reason you should never trust that your database is being accesses by *your* code, and always look out for malicious users who will write their own code against your database and APIs.

It sounds like users should be assumed to have a regular `USER` role when they are created, and only certain users get a special role. You can either write your data access code to assume that `rule == 'USER'` if it isn't specified, or you can use a trusted environment to set the initial role.

A trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions, is a place where you can be sure that the code that runs is the code that you wrote. In this case, I think Cloud Functions is the perfect fit, as it allows you to [automatically run code on Google's servers in response to a user account being created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events). Based on that documentation you could mark the new user as a `USER` with:

```
exports.setDefaultRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  return admin.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).update({ rule: "USER" });
});
```

You'll note that we can't access the `username` in this code, as that may not have been set yet when this `onCreate` runs. That's why we're only updating the `rule` property of the user's database node instead of setting it completely.